# Testing Push Notification in TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, push-notification

I am installing an app which has push notification feature.

I have set

1. Xcode - [My App] -> Capabilities -> Push Notification (on), Background mode Remote Notification (on)
2. Also I checked that in Apple Development account, Provisioning Profile and App Id displaying Push Notification Enabled.

I archived the file and put it on app store to install from Test Flight. However when I installed the app from Test Flight and open the app first time, Push Notification setting alert doesn't show up. I checked Setting - Notification from my phone, but the app is not in the list.

Did I missing something to enable Push Notification? Don't know what else I can investigate to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to write code in app delegate or link push notification module. Please check react native doc for it https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#content

Also, I suggest to use this module for push notification in react native app https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification